# XBAP iFrame in hidden div problem in FireFox

Tags: firefox, html, xbap

I have an XBAP that is in an IFRAME, wrap inside a DIV, which can be hidden and shown at the users will.  But, in FireFox, after hiding the DIV and later re-showing it, the XBAP disappears.

I have tried all sorts of refresh methods I can find, but nothing seems to work.  I don't want to reload the XBAP as its showing information specifically available at the time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onstatechange was causing the problem.  Writing a JavaScript method around this to detect the browser type fixed the issue.